# Vue component not showing

Tags: laravel-5.3, vuejs2, vue-component

I followed the series codetube "youtube clone" and I did everything like the Alex but the Vue component not working. I am not working on localhost but on server. I would be very glad for any suggestions.

My app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');



Vue.component('videoup', require('./components/VideoUpload.vue'));


const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

My VideoUpload.vue file:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Upload</div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                    ...
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

My blade file:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <videoup></videoup> 

@endsection
```

My app.blade file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
<!--    <link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">


    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script>
        window.Laravel = <?php echo json_encode([
            'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
        ]); ?>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">

        @include('layouts.partials._navigation')

        @yield('content')



    </div>



    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My gulfpile.js:

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

require('laravel-elixir-vue-2');

require('laravel-elixir-webpack-official');





elixir((mix) => {
    mix.sass('app.scss')
            .webpack('app.js');
});
```

My webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          // vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js'
    }
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map',
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
};
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console? My initial thoughts are that you have not defined a render function as `require('vue')` pulls in the `runtime-only` build, which does not include the template compiler.

Comment: No I dont have any errors, when I reload page everything works without error but I dont see Vue component template on the page....I also tried `require('vue')` but nothing happend

Answer (score 6):

It's difficult to debug your setup because I have no idea what tutorial you followed, how you are bundling your code (`webpack` or `browserify`) or what build tools you are using (`gulp`, `elixir` etc), but I think the most important thing is to understand how `Vue` works, and then you will be able to better understand how to solve this yourself.

Firstly, vue has two builds - a `standalone build` and a `runtime-only build`. The difference between these is that the `standalone build` includes a template compiler and the `runtime-only build` does not.

### Render Functions

`Vue` compiles templates in to render functions to work (which are just javascript functions), it doesn't use `HTML` at all, so if you haven't written a render function or you haven't `pre-compiled` your components (using `.vue` files and a bundler like `browserify` or `webpack`) then you must use the `standalone build`; and this includes the base component itself, so the important thing to know is:

> ### If you are trying to use a component inside anything other than a `.vue` file you need to use the standalone build.

because you need the compiler to turn the `HTML` into a render function.

So, looking at your code, you are trying to use your component inside a `.blade.php` file, which isn't a `single file component` so you will need the standalone build in your project.

When using `npm`, vue imports the `runtime-only` build by default:

```
// ES6
import `Vue` from `vue` // this imports the runtime-only build

// ES5
var Vue = require('vue'); // this requires the runtime-only build
```

But you need to make sure you are using the `standalone build`, and how you do this depends on whether you use `webpack` or `browserify`. If you are using webpack, you need to add the following to your webpack config:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js'
  }
}
```

If you are using `browserify` you will need to add the following to your `package.json`:

```
"browser": {
  "vue": "vue/dist/vue.common"
},
```

And also make sure that `resources/assets/views/layouts/app.blade.php` wraps everything in a `div` with the id `app`:

```
...
<body>
<div id="app">
   ...
</div>
</body>
...
```

### Update

Based on your `webpack config` it looks like your issue is here:

```
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
```

This says you are compiling `main.js` in the `src` folder and outputting it to the `dist` folder as `build.js`.

Laravel uses a different structure, so you will need to change this to:

```
  entry: './resources/assets/js/app.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public/js'),
    publicPath: '/public/',
    filename: 'app.js'
  },
```

This now says, compile `resources/assets/js/app.js` and output the file to `public/js/app.js`. I don't use `webpack` myself so that may need a little tweaking, but that should get your project up and running.

Comment: Thank for your reply. Sorry that I didnt write all required informations but I am very new to Vue. I  have added  code from gulpfile.js and webpack.config.js to my question som you can chek it. I have checked my file and everything looks ok I have `resolve: {
  alias: {
    'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js'
  } 
}` in `webpack.config` and also everything in `app.blade.php` is wrapped in `<div>` with id `app` so I cannot find the source of my problem. I would be verz glad for any suggestions

Comment: Or let me know which informations you need and I will post it...Thanks in advance

Comment: @craig_h.....Thanks for all your effort. I tried it but nothing changed.....Very frustrating

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. the following solved it for me..

I changed:

```
require('./components/mycomponent.vue')
```

to:

```
import MyComponent from "./components/mycomponent.vue";
```